# Getting compile error while creating dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

```
queryStr+ = 'AND Sales_Order__r.sales_year__c =' +\'' +:strYear+\'';
```

This is my string.strYear is the year value which i want to add dynamicaly.

I am getting an error `"Compile Error: unexpected token: '=' "`

Can someone help please

Comment: queryStr+ = 'AND Sales_Order__r.sales_year__c = :strYear';

Comment: try `queryStr+ = 'AND Sales_Order__r.sales_year__c =\''+Name+'\''`

Comment: its giving me the same error as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code to:

```
queryStr += 'AND Sales_Order__r.sales_year__c = :strYear ';
```

I think you had a space between + and =